# How to use uuid as primary key type with sequelize-typescript annotations?

Tags: typescript, annotations, uuid, sequelize-typescript

I'd like to use UUID instead of the default autoincremented integer that Sequelize impose. Note that I have to use the npm package [sequelize-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-typescript)

Here's my attempt so far.

```
export class SequelizeIterationModel extends Model<IterationModelAttributes> {
  @IsUUID(4)
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column({
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    primaryKey: true,
  })
  public id!: string;

  @BelongsTo(() => SequelizeBuildModel)
  public build!: SequelizeBuildModel;

  @ForeignKey(() => SequelizeBuildModel)
  public buildId!: number;

  @Column({ type: DataTypes.JSON })
  public config!: Record<string, unknown>;
}
```

But I can't get rid fo this error: `invalid input syntax for integer: "6ecfcc0e-b0de-4991-bf45-e190534293c2"`

How can I achieve that?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript), you can leave out the `primaryKey: true` property when using `@PrimaryKey`-annotation. Does it help to remove one of the two redundant identifiers?

Comment: Furthermore, you are always writing `DataTypes`, whereas the package's export is called `DataType`. How do you import the dependency?

Answer (score 2):

This would be the correct order:

```
@PrimaryKey
@Default(DataType.UUIDV4)
@Column(DataType.UUID)
public id: any;
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be completely tangential, but I recall some time ago using this library and having a real pain with something akin to this. What ended up being the fix for me (or rather, the error) was that the decorators prefer a certain order.

It’s more likely that my suggestion is completely useless— but hey. Best case scenario, you juggle the decorator order around and it works. Worst case scenario, you’ve wasted precious jugglin’ time. Worth a shot.